# How to integrate Simpsons rule using Scipy to plot a 1D graph

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, integral, simpsons-rule

i need some help, i have an assignment to code an integration of a function using simpsons rule. I need to use the inbuilt scipy integratesimps function to plot a 1D graph. I just don't know where to start. I think i have to get a list/array of each value of y for the function that corresponds to each values of x: e.g

if my function is x^2
then when 
x is 0 y is 0,
x is 1 y is 1,
x is 2 y is 4,
and so on up to a huge limit...

and then use integrate.simps(y,x) where y are all the y values as shown above and x are all the corresponding x values.

However, i can't get it to work at all...has anyone got any examples of a graph plot for a function of x^2 using integrate.simps(y,x)?

here is what i've got so far:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10,10,N)
N = 100

yarray = []

def f(x):
    return x**2

for i in x :
    y = f(i)
    yarray.append(y)

print(yarray)


E = integrate.simps(yarray,x)
print(E)

plt.plot(x,E)
```

Comment: What do you mean by plotting a 1D graph, are you trying to plot x^2, the integration of x^2, or something else?

Comment: i'm trying to plot the integration of x^2, using the integrate.simps()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to calculate the integral value for every range of x, from [-10,-10] to [-10,10]

This example code plots

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return x**2

N = 100
x = np.linspace(-10,10,N)


integrals = []
x_range = []
y_range = []
for i in x:
    x_range.append(i)
    y_range.append(f(i))
    integral = integrate.simps(y_range, x_range)
    integrals.append(integral)

plt.plot(x, integrals)
plt.show()
```

To wrap it up

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def integrals(f, xs):
    x_range = []
    y_range = []
    results = []
    for x in xs:
        x_range.append(x)
        y_range.append(f(x))
        integral = integrate.simps(y_range, x_range)
        results.append(integral)
    return results

def f(x, b):
    return (x-b)**2

xs = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)

plt.plot(xs, integrals(lambda x: f(x, 0), xs), label='b=0')
plt.plot(xs, integrals(lambda x: f(x, 2), xs), label='b=2')
plt.plot(xs, integrals(lambda x: f(x, 4), xs), label='b=4')
plt.title('$y(x) = \int_{-10}^{x}(t-b)^2dt$')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

and you get[image]

Comment: Thanks! that works really well, what happens if i have a variable in my function? e.g (x-b)^2 where b is changing

Comment: Should Y not be zero where X=0? What's causing everything to shift up?